# How to put object into string and print

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a script that takes variables from an html form and sends them to a php script. I query new data based on these numbers and format them into a string to be sent back to the script. The problem is that my php variables aren't printing and I think it is because they are objects. Here is my code:

```
//GET VENDOR PO NUMBER AND APPEND ONCHANGE OF # OF EXISTING POS
            $('#numvendpo').mouseover(function(){
            var countpre = $(this).val();
            var p = $('#pro').val();
            var c = $('#custponumhold').val();
            var v = $('#vendorid').val();
            var cp = (parseInt(countpre)+1);
            var data_String;
             data_String = 'p='+p+'&c='+c+'&v='+v+'&cp='+cp;
             $.post('ft-final-v-po-num.php',data_String,function(data){
                   var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                   $('#vendponum').val(data);
                });
            });
```

I then post the values to this php script:

```
<?php
require "../inc/dbinfo.inc";

$p = $_POST['p'];
$c =$_POST['c'];
$v = $_POST['v'];
$cp = $_POST['cp'];

if ($c == 'null') { //cant use (!$customerpo) because $customerpo is passing the string of 'null' instead of the actual null value              
$c = NULL;         //so we change that to the actual null value
}

$getprojectnum = "SELECT ProjectNumber FROM tblProjects WHERE PROJECTNOID = '$p'"; //check
$getcustomerpo = "SELECT SequentialPONum FROM tblCustomerPOs WHERE CustomerPOID = '$c'"; //check
$getvendornum = "SELECT VendorNumber FROM tblVendors WHERE VENDORID = '$v'"; //check

$acpnhold = $conn->query($getprojectnum);
$accphold = $conn->query($getcustomerpo);
$acvnhold = $conn->query($getvendornum);

$acpn = mysqli_fetch_object($acpn);
$accp = mysqli_fetch_object($accp);
$acvn = mysqli_fetch_object($acvn);

if($c){
  $string = $acpn.'-'.$accp.'-'.$acvn.'-'.$cp;
  echo json_encode($string);
  exit();
}elseif(!$c){
  $string = $acpn.'-'.$acvn.'-'.$cp;
  echo json_encode($string);
  exit();
}else{
  echo json_encode('Error');
  exit();
}
?>
```

The response on my webpage is `---2` instead of (ex: `18000-1-2-2`). As mentioned earlier I think it is because they are objects but I am not quite sure. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You every heard of sql injections? Use prepared statements for your queries!

Comment: Enable error reporting and fix all undefined variable errors. For example, what the heck is `$acpn`?

Comment: dump your variables or print_r them so you can see what it has maybe as it is object you could use $acvn->VendorNumber instead and others will follow

Comment: I noticed that your first if-condition is running, but the check only guarantees the variable reference and not it's content. One idea to debug -- encode an array of the variables you're passing as JSON and print out that string as a response, see what you're getting? Like this -- $arr = array($a, $b, $c);
$json = json_encode($arr);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this bit:

```
$acpn = mysqli_fetch_object($acpn);
$accp = mysqli_fetch_object($accp);
$acvn = mysqli_fetch_object($acvn);
```

From the php docs:

> object mysqli_fetch_object ( mysqli_result $result [, string $class_name = "stdClass" [, array $params ]] )

Your `$acpn` `$accp` and `$acvn` are not result objects. They are not even defined before you use them in those calls.

This should get the single column from each query result:

```
$acpn = $acpnhold->fetch_row()[0];
$accp = $accphold->fetch_row()[0];
$acvn = $acvnhold->fetch_row()[0];
```

Bear in mind you still have a major SQL Injection vulnerability with the original query calls.

Comment: Awesome. These inputs are only selected via dropdown. Forgive my ignorance but does this not stop any user input other than the options given?

Comment: @Jordan: Data can be crafted in any way and posted to your script without use of the form.

Comment: As Abra mentioned. ANY variables coming in on GET and POST (and REQUEST) are never to be trusted. Always sanitize them, and if going into a db query, using prepared statements helps safeguard all the sneaky ways bad data can mangle a query.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this code below:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ft-final-v-po-num.php',
    data: { 
        'p': p, 
        'c': c, 
        'v': v, 
        'cp': cp
    },
    success: function(msg){
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('#vendponum').val(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: still responds with '---2'